# How can i check each item in a list one by one, with a delay in between?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game where the player gets shown a pattern, and has to repeat it. If the player gets it right the game adds 1 to the sequence each time.

right now I'm trying to get the game to show the pattern. They way i have it set up is that the game pattern is stored in a list. 1 means the top left will light up 2 the top right etc. and every time the player list is == to the game list a number will be added to game list

```
def addlist():
    if playerpattern == gamepattern:
        gamepattern.append(random.randint(1, 4))

def idk():
    for number in gamepattern:
        if number == 1:
            Gamestate = 1
        if number == 2:
            Gamestate = 2
        if number == 3:
            Gamestate = 3
        if number == 4:
            Gamestate = 4
def show():
    if playerpattern == gamepattern:
            if Gamestate == 1:
                topleft.color = (255, 0, 0)
            else:
                topleft.color = (100, 0, 0)
            if Gamestate == 2:
                topright.color = (0, 0, 255)
            else:
                topright.color = (0, 0, 175)
            if Gamestate == 3:
                bottomleft.color = (0, 255, 0)
            else:
                bottomleft.color = (0, 175, 0)
            if Gamestate == 4:
                bottomright.color = (255, 255, 0)
            else:
                bottomright.color = (175, 175, 0)

playing = True
gamepattern = []
playerpattern = []

while playing:
    clock.tick(10)
    print(gamepattern)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseclick()

    mousehover()
    addlist()
    show()
    draw()

pygame.quit()
```

This doesn't actually work its just all I could come up with really. I basically need a function that checks a list from beginning to end with a little bit of time in between.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you mean by "check a list from beginning to end with a little bit of time in between?" In between what? Why do you need this delay? Your code is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and cannot be run, so it's hard to say what should be fixed here.

Comment: @Valentino The delay is for when the game is showing the patern so it can show you at a nice pace like pattern[0] + half a second + patern[1] + half a second + ..., . So the squares could light up almost rythmically if that makes sense

Comment: You could check the list element by element, draw what you need do draw and add a delay with `time.sleep()`. What I cannot understand from your code is what you want to draw on the screen, so unless you show a MCVE that is up to you.

Comment: @Valentino i thought this would be the MCVE  im basically just changing the colors of squares made through a class. (Ex bottomright.color is the square on the bottom right)

Comment: It isn't. `idk()` function is not used anywhere, could be removed. `mouseclick()` and `mousehover()` functions are not provided, I can guess from the name what they are supposed to do, but no idea how they works internally and how they are integrated with the rest of the code. `topleft`, `topright`, no idea what they are. You have just mentioned a class which is not shown in your code. If I copy paste your code in a file and try to run it, no way it will run. This is very far from being a MCVE.

Comment: @Valentino right

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are recreating the old Simon game.  You're on the right track.  Break down the things that need to be done into functions and go from there.  You will need functions that:

- Check to see if the guess is correct (see below)
- add to the solution if they got it right.  Call this conditionally...
- capture the player's guess through mouse clicks
- reset everything if they got it wrong ...

Then all you need to do is make up a main loop that goes through the motions with some conditional statements.  you can add time delays wherever you see fit.

```
In [1]: solution = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]                                           

In [2]: guess_1 =  [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]                                           

In [3]: guess_2 =  [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4]                                           

In [4]: def check_answer(guess, soln): 
   ...:     if guess == soln: 
   ...:         return True 
   ...:     return False 
   ...:                                                                         

In [5]: check_answer(guess_1, solution)                                         
Out[5]: True

In [6]: check_answer(guess_2, solution)                                         
Out[6]: False
```

Comment: i get confused on how to use the tome delay in the main game loop, anyway you could do a quick example? I appreciate your help

Comment: Well, I’m not too experienced with pygame, but you could just use `time` and `time.sleep()`.  That should work